# How to recursively calculate mean of values based on values present in another cell of the same row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mean, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with two columns of values, containing 1000 values each. The first column (column A) contains these values:

```
W
W
W
T
T
T
```

The second column (column B) contains these values:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Here is an image of the spreadsheet:

[image]

Can you please tell me if there is a way to recursively calculate the mean of those values in column B that have the same value in column A? In my case, the output should be a new column that looks like this:

```
2
5
```

As you can see, "2" is the mean of values in column B that has "W" in column A, while "5" is the mean of values in column B that has "T" in column A.

Comment: I'd say you need to look into a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question can be handled using [the `SubTotals` feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a), using `Average()` as the function to be used (instead of the default `Sum()` function).